# UPC code proof help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

i'm trying to prove the following problem..

```
1. Prove that if a single digit of a valid UPC is changed then the new code is not valid.
```

Answer - When the question asks to prove it, does it mean to litteraly do a mathematical problem where I prove that a UPC code is valid and then alter any digit and prove that that is not valid? (If so, that's really easy) On the other hand, does it want me to generalize the proof?

```
2. If two digits are changed in a valid UPC, the new code may or may not be valid. Determine the type of changes to two digits that result in a valid code, and determine the change to two digits that result in a code that is not valid. Justify both of your answers.
```

Answer - For this problem, I need a direction to go about solving the problem rather than computing various mathematical checks.

Thanks guys!

Comment: If the sum of odd position digits remain the same the check digit will remain the same. This is also true for even position digits. An example would be two odd position digits of 1&9 total (10) could be replaced with 2&8, 3&7, 4&6, 5&5, 6&4, 7&3, 8&2, 9&1. If the sum remains constant the check digit will also remain constant. Odd & Even position digits can be changed, but it gets a little more involved. Also UPC's have a leading (Zero) that is not displayed in the human readables. So if the smaller digit on the left reads 3 it is really a 03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe part of the UPC code is a checksum-you could have told us that.  If so, you should be able to prove that changing any one digit makes the sum not check.  All the noncheck digits are interchangeable, and clearly changing the check digit causes it to fail.  For 2, you can just demonstrate one change of two digits that is valid and one change that is not.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the earlier questions are very easy and don't expect you to do much if anything beyond what is explicitly asked. Later questions go more in depth and typically expect you to draw on results obtained answering earlier questions.

For the first question, all you have to do is show that changing only one digit of the UPC makes it invalid, nothing more, nothing less. It's enough to show that each possible choice for a particular digit corresponds to a different check digit. For example, in GTIN-$12$:

- `0000000000000`
- `0000000000017`
- `0000000000024`
- `0000000000031`
- `0000000000048`
- `0000000000055`
- `0000000000062`
- `0000000000079`
- `0000000000086`
- `0000000000093`

What you have to understand is that one of the design considerations for the UPC system is operator dyslexia, and, [as the OEIS points out](http://oeis.org/A231963), this is still cause for concern today, despite the ubiquitousness of optical scanners. Generally, a dyslexic person will make the mistake of exchanging two adjacent digits. Compare:

- `0000000000017`
- `0000000000109`

It's possible, but far less likely, for a dyslexic person to switch non-adjacent digits, and that can easily result in the same check digit:

- `0000000000017`
- `0000000001007`
- `0000000100007`
- `0000010000007`
- `0001000000007`
- `0100000000007`

And similarly

- `0000000000109`
- `0000000010009`
- `0000001000009`
- `0000100000009`
- `0010000000009`
- `1000000000009`

Addition is commutative, but as you already know, the multiplier for the odd-indexed digits is different from the multiplier in the even-indexed positions. Exchanging two odd-indexed or two even-indexed digits does not change the check digit. But there are only ten possibilities for the check digit and millions of possible combinations for the other digits. If you want the check digit to be $7$, you can do:

- `0000000000017`
- `0000000000147`
- `0000000000277`
- `0000000000307`
- `0000000000437`
- etc.